# Resources are called from /appName but from root

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm usign spring boot.
When I deploy my app under a AWS balancer, the app is calling some resources from myDir/myAppName. But the style resources are called from root, like myDir/.

E.g. myDir/myAppName/index.html is accesible for loadBalancer. But myDir/myStilesheet.css isn't accesible.

How can I set that resources (css, etc) under myDir/myAppName?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the **WebMvcConfigurer** interface and override the **void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)** method.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("myDir/myAppName/myStilesheet.css")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/css/myStilesheet.css");
}}
```